# Range.Select gets an error after looping once

Tags: excel, vba

Hi Im using this formula to loop through specific worksheets, and then gets a certain range and copies it to another sheet. When I first run the macro, it's successful in the first loop. But once it goes back to start again the loop, the error occurs..

The Error says.

> Run Time Error 1004: Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed.

This is the line that gets highlighted :

```
ws.Range(StartCell, ws.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub sheetLoop()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Set StartCell = Range("A10")

Windows("PMP Open Seats Report - 11-05-20 -.xls").Activate

For Each ws In Worksheets

 If ws.Name = "16 - 30 Days" Or ws.Name = "31 - 60 Days" Or ws.Name = "61 - 90 Days" Or ws.Name = "90+ Days" Then
  With ws
  ws.Activate
  
  LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  LastColumn = ws.Cells(StartCell.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  
  MsgBox LastRow
  MsgBox LastColumn
  MsgBox ws.Name
  

  'Select Range
  ws.Range(StartCell, ws.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy
  
  Selection.Copy
  Sheets("RAW").Activate
  Range("A1").Select
  Selection.End(xlDown).Select
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Range("A1").Select
 
  
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  
 End With
  
 End If
Next ws

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StartCell` is not fully qualified, so it is based on whatever sheet is active at the time you give it a value.

```
Set StartCell = Range("A10")
```

Move that line inside the loop, after `ws` has a value, and then include the sheet reference.

```
With ws
  ws.Activate
  Set StartCell = ws.Range("A10")
```

See if that does what you expect.

Comment: Wow. It really solved the problem! Thanks for your help! I'm new to VBA and macro. Since yesterday, I'm doing this one. Thanks for your help!